# How to fix: Error code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 comun(s)?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'd like to return one row in my function, but I get this error code.

> Error code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)?

I have these tables:

airport

```
airport_id, 
city, 
country, 
name, 
phonenumber
```

and

route

```
route_number, 
start_date, 
finish_date, 
time, 
start_airport_id, 
finish_airport_id
```

I want to write a function that I give in its parameters start_country, finish_country and date and I want to return one row.

So this is my code:

```
FUNCTION `search`(start_country varchar(50), finish_country varchar(50), dat date)
RETURNS varchar(255) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE start_id, finish_id varchar(50);

    if (start_country is null ) or (finish_country is null) or (dat is null) then
        return 'Parameters are required.';
    end if;

    SELECT airport_id INTO start_id FROM airport where country=start_country;
    SELECT airport_id INTO finish_id FROM airport where country=finish_country;

    if (start_id is null) or (finish_id is null) then
        return 'There is no such country.';
    else
        RETURN (SELECT * FROM route
                WHERE start_airport_id=start_id
                AND  finish_airport_id=finish_id
                AND start_date=dat );

     end if;
END
```

I write to select

```
search('Hungary', 'France', '2019-03-08')
```

and I'd like to get:

```
route_number | start_date | finish_date | time |start_airprot_id| finish_airport_id
AI1000         2019-03-08    2019-03-08   3hours        1                2
```

But I get Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Your return makes no sense, mysql expect a varchar as return value and you give him as table. **instead** using a fuction use a **procedure**

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear?  You're trying to put a table into a variable.